# Sociallogin not appearing in Drupal when caching with Boost

Tags: caching, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm using the Sociallogin module in Drupal 7 along with the Boost module. The Boost module requires that js/css caching is enabled.

The sociallogin widget does not appear either as a user block, social login block or on the user/login page.

I've got a cloned dev site happening where js/css caching is disabled and the social login block works fine, so we can probably safely assume that it has to do with the caching.

Unfortunately I'm going to need Boost and caching for my production site.

Got any ideas for a workaround?

Here are the errors;

Warning: file_get_contents(//hub.loginradius.com/include/js/LoginRadius.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in drupal_build_js_cache() (line 4940 of /mysite/drupal-7.22/includes/common.inc).

And in the console.log;

Uncaught ReferenceError: LoginRadius_SocialLogin is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to have corrected itself. I can only assume it was an upgrade to the api at their (loginradius.com) end.